# get all listed data in listview one by one and insert it into mysql database

Tags: android

I want to insert name of students with their attendance status marked in radio button from list view in android to MySQL database one by one means in different row each name and with their attendance status how can i do it ....some thing like this image
[like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBDuS.jpg)

please help me i have no any idea how to do it.please its arrgent This is just my selectstud java class

```
  package com.attendance.olana.instructor;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by olana on 18/02/2018.
 */
public class studlist extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.studlist);
    }




}
```

Comment: are you familiar with networking calls ??and web services?

Comment: no sir no clue.

Comment: read this about networking calls https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/ and this to learn how to build web services https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/ ..i suggest that you have to read and practices ...then post the errors that you feel its tremendous for you...ok sir

Comment: I already parsed the data from database using json and fill in listview  what i want to do is to insert the lists in listview into database....simply getting the text/lists in the listview one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're fetching data from a `MySQL` DB in form of `JSON` into your App's `ListView` from a server, I'm assuming you're familiar with the concept of `AsyncTask` or `Threading`, `List` & `ListView`.
Now, you want to submit the attendance of each student marked with a `CheckBox` or `RadioButton`. **So make a `Class` with 2 mandatory data variable: `String name` and `boolean attendance`**. Suppose the class name is `Student`. When fetching data from Server you will create an object of this class and store it in the `List` with the variable name fulfilled(Since for now you're just fetching the name). Consequently, your `List` will have the generic type `Student`, i.e., `List<Student>`.
Now in the `onClick` event of the `CheckBox` or `RadioButton` of each row of the `ListView` you will retrieve the position of the row and whether  the student is marked absent or present and change the consequent item of the `List<Student>`.
When **Submit button** is clicked, you will send all the data to the Server. The Server side script should retrieve the data and change the attendance accordingly matched via id or name of the student.
NOTE: It is better to keep an 'id' variable in the Student class instead of 'name' variable since it will reduce the data sent to Server as well as increase precision when matching data in Database.

Comment: I understand what you have writen but would you mind me to send sample code if you have....please sir

Comment: The sample code requires too many things that cannot be written without precise requirements..... I would suggest you take some time to learn what I've told you. Moreover, to code what I've said i need to create everything your question relies on, the local server, PHP or Node Scripts, etc etc..... that would be very time consuming.

Comment: And if you're satisfied with my answer please mark it as correct.